# How would I select specific attributes from the foreign table

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

Assume we have two models defined as **Post** and **Tag**.  A **Post** and a **Tag** are associated via a many-to-many association.  In Sequelize, I'd like to get all the posts, and additionally, all their corresponding tags.  Additionally, I am attemping to reduce the data selected from the query, that is, I only need the Tag.id after the tables are joined.

I have tried the following:

```
var find = {
    attributes: [
        'id',
        'text',
        'createdAt'
    ],
    include: [
        {
            model: Tag,
            attributes: [
                'id'
            ]
        }
    ]
};

Post.findAll(find).complete(function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Unfortunately, this returns JSON which contains extra attributes, such as the "postsTag" join table information...

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "HI",
    "createdAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
    "tags": [{
        "id": 1,
        "postsTag": {
            "createdAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
            "TagId": 1,
            "PostId": 1
        }
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "postsTag": {
            "createdAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
            "TagId": 2,
            "PostId": 1
        }
    }]
}]
```

Ultimately, I would want the following:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "text": "HI",
    "createdAt": "2014-08-29T15:41:33.000Z",
    "tags": [{
        "id": 1 
    }, {
        "id": 2
        }
    }]
}]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be much appriciated!  I am sure I have just missed some important information from reading through the Sequelize documentation.